# Ubuntu splash screen changed to edubuntu, why did it happen and how do I change it back?

Tags: edubuntu

I recently noticed during a reboot of my machine that a splash page came up saying Edubuntu, which I understand is a particular flavour of Ubuntu. When I installed Ubuntu, it never used to say that, and it was not the version I installed. I installed 12.04 32 bit.

Can anyone explain how my operating system changed to change to Edubuntu? can this happen through some kind of system update?

Comment: Sounds like a mystery. ;) Please note that also Edubuntu has version 12.04 32 bit. Are you quite sure it wasn't that ISO file you used for the installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install `edbuntu-desktop`? Either way simply remove the `plymouth-theme-edubuntu` package:

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-edubuntu
```

and reboot.

Comment: Sounds like a plausible explanation. OTOH, the Edubuntu default background looks nice. :)

Comment: Ah, would of been quicker if I hadn't had to confirm I'm not a robot :)

Comment: @Wilf Tsk, that day when computers can't tell a wolf in a hat from a robot.. Silly computers ;)

Answer (score 4):

You installed [`edubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/edubuntu-desktop), which is a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) that installs the Edubuntu desktop and the packages it wants/need to work. This includes [`edubuntu-artwork`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/edubuntu-artwork), which installs [`plymouth-theme-edubuntu`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/plymouth-theme-edubuntu), the theme you see on boot.

You can remove this with:

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-edubuntu
```